# insert into select, working with two tables from different servers error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My code:

```
 INSERT INTO lclTabla
     SELECT * 
     FROM openquery([LD_DB_A0FCCD_ALDOLANCHO], 
                    'SELECT * 
                     FROM [DB_A0FCCD_aldolancho].[dbo].[servTable]')
     WHERE 
         lclTabla.dni = [LD_DB_A0FCCD_ALDOLANCHO].[DB_A0FCCD_aldolancho].[dbo].[servTable].[dni]
```

is causing an error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   The multi-part identifier "lclTabla.dni" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   The multi-part identifier "LD_DB_A0FCCD_ALDOLANCHO.DB_A0FCCD_aldolancho.dbo.servTable.dni" could not be bound.

I want to insert where the id from local table is the same in the server table

Please help!!! In T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run cross server query, You must follow proper naming convention 
i.e. [server name].[database name].[schema name].[table name]

In your query, I can see wrong naming convention in - 
"[LD_DB_A0FCCD_ALDOLANCHO].[DB_A0FCCD_aldolancho].[dbo].[servTable].[dni]"